# Pass variables to code <input type="image" src="imageSrc;" >

Tags: javascript, variables, image, src

hope someone can help a noob.  Many thanks in advance.

I have an index page with links to hundreds of other pages holding song words.
I have built each song page but it would be MUCH simpler to have one MASTER page that took a variable from the index page and found the corresponding words (which exist as png graphics.)

I have sorted Step 1 - I can pass a variable from the index page to the master page using:

```
<a href="javascript: window.open('MUSIC/beatles/mastertest2.html?song=ER', '_parent')">
```

where `song=ER` is the variable to display the words for Eleanor Rigby.  For Step 2, I can also retrieve that information in the master page with:

```
var imageSrc = (qs("song")+".png");  document.write(imageSrc);
```

which will display the text `ER.png` which is the name of the image I want to display.

For Step 3 I am trying to get this same variable read into:

```
<input type="image" src="imageSrc;">
```

to display the picture.  I have searched this and other forums for days now and nothing suggested works for me.  I could be missing out an essential early step in the coding?

**Update**:

My master html file has this code to retrieve the variable:

```
function qs(search_for) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parms = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
        var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0 && search_for == parms[i].substring(0,pos)) {
            return parms[i].substring(pos+1);;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

And it uses this code to disply the variable (appended with .png) just to prove to me that it is getting through:

```
var imageSrc = (qs("song")+".png");
document.write(imageSrc);
```

Then I am trying to feed the variable into a routine to display the png selected. The next script doesn't work but I am thrashing about trying anything right now:

```
var imageSrc = (qs("song")+".png");
document.write(imageSrc);

<input type="image" src="@imageSrc;" border="0" value="Notes" onClick="placeIt(); showIt()">
<input id="song-image" type="image">
var imageSrc = 'ER.png';
var input = document.getElementById('song-image');
input.src = imageSrc;
```

Comment: I have updated your question with your comments. The code is easier to read in your question. You can always update your question with the small `edit` link below your question. Please review the changes, if everything is as you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already `<input type="image">` in your HTML page, you must add an `id` and then set it's `src` attribute with

HTML:

```
<input id="song-image" type="image">
```

JS:

```
var imageSrc = 'http://www.lorempixel.com/200/100';
var input = document.getElementById('song-image');
input.src = imageSrc;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYV4Y/) for testing.

Comment: My master html file has this code in the header section to retrieve the variable:   <script language="javascript">
      function qs(search_for) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var parms = query.split('&');
  for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
   var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
   if (pos > 0  && search_for == parms[i].substring(0,pos)) {
    return parms[i].substring(pos+1);;
   }
  }
  return "";
 }
</script>

Comment: And it uses this code in the body section to display the variable (appended with .png) just to prove to me that it is getting through: <script type="text/javascript">  
  var imageSrc = (qs("song")+".png");
document.write(imageSrc);
</script>

Comment: Then I am trying to feed the variable into a routine to display the png selected.  The next script doesn't work but I am thrashing about trying anything right now:  <script type="text/javascript">  
  var imageSrc = (qs("song")+".png");
document.write(imageSrc);
</script>

<script>
<input type="image" src="@imageSrc;"  border="0" value="Notes" onClick="placeIt(); showIt()">

<input id="song-image" type="image">
var imageSrc = 'ER.png';
var input = document.getElementById('song-image');
input.src = imageSrc; 
</script>

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, its very simple. Are you looking for this?

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'image';
input.src = imageSrc;
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

If you can print the variable `imageSrc` using document.write, then you can use it like shown above.

Comment: Olaf - thanks but I can't make it work.  I have tried to post the entire code for the page but this system keeps curtailing its display - how do I post the code in its entirety?

Comment: Olaf - I tidied my code up around yours and it has worked - brilliant - thank you so much.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it is correct and solved your problem. It encourages people to help more. @MikeLydiat